# Flutter Video Player Playing In Slow Motion In Release Builds

Tags: android, ios, flutter, video-player, flutter-video-player

I've been using video_player: ^0.10.11+2 to play and display videos in my app, every runs smooth when i'm testing on my device with flutter run. But when i do a release build on both Android and iOS, the video plays in slow motion and without sound. Sometimes it plays in slow motion and also plays like its gotten scratches.

Is this a known issue or am doing something completely wrong.

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: @ErickFilho No, I ended up using flick_video_player. Lats a few features but it works well and easy to use.

Comment: any update on this? or are you keep on using that library? @marvinralph

Comment: @Irfandi I had to use flick_video_player